# Populate an array/list with sums

Tags: c#, sum

How can I populate an array or list with sums that don't go higher than 10?
I could do this with 3 arrays where 2 of them hold random numbers which the answer is not higher than 10, and a 3rd array to have the answers in it.

But that's kind of an ugly way of doing this.

To be more clear with what I want:

```
1 + 1 = 2
5 + 5 = 10
3 + 2 = 5
```

etc etc

The user only gets to see the 1 + 1 at first. And when the time is up, the user gets to see the answer.

So does anyone has another solution then what I'm about to tryout?

Comment: could you generate them on the fly, num1 = Random(0,10), num2 = Random(0, 10-num1)?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what the usage is, why do you need to store the answers? couldn't you just calculate those on the fly?

Comment: Yea that's a possibility, but the sum will be presented in a label (string). Doing all those convertings string/int etc is just too much overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you are trying to do something like this. This compiled but is untested. Noted how to create these pairs using the random number generator and subtraction.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        struct addition_pairs{
            public int first;
            public int second;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 

         List<addition_pairs> main_list;
         main_list = new List<addition_pairs>();
       //TODO call populate_list and choose how many sets you want.

        }

        private void populate_list(int how_many, List<addition_pairs> list)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < how_many; i++)
            {
                Random random = new Random();
                int randomNumber1 = random.Next(0, 10);
                addition_pairs insert = new addition_pairs();
                insert.first = randomNumber1;
                insert.second = random.Next(0, 10-randomNumber1);
                list.Add(insert);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: FIXED so it doesn't add to 10 every time LOL. I passed math i promise

Comment: Hi, thanks, this looks promising, I'll try this out and let you know how it worked out. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a 2D array.

```
int numSums = 4;
int[,] sums = new int[numSums,3];

// 1 + 1 = 2
sums[0,0] = 1;
sums[0,1] = 1;
sums[0,2] = sums[0,0] + sums[0,1];

// 5 + 5 = 10
sums[1,0] = 5;
sums[1,1] = 5;
sums[1,2] = sums[1,0] + sums[1,1];

// 3 + 2 = 5
sums[2,0] = 3;
sums[2,1] = 2;
sums[2,2] = sums[2,0] + sums[2,1];

// 2 + 2 = 4
sums[3,0] = 2;
sums[3,1] = 2;
sums[3,2] = sums[3,0] + sums[3,1];
```

You can also use a class to achieve the the cleanest effect.

```
private List<Equation> sums = new List<Equation>();

public MyConstructor() {
    sums.Add(new Equation(5, 5));
    Console.WriteLine (sums[0].a + " + " + sums[0].b  + " = " + sums[0].sum);
}

private class Equation {
    public int a;
    public int b;

    public int sum { 
        get { return a + b; } 
    }

    public Equation(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, but I have to create like 20 of those sums on the fly. Writing them all out would be even crazier then what i was gonna do initally.

Comment: The best thing to do here if you can't do it on the fly for some reason is to use a class (see edit to my original answer).